# How to bind an object to JNDI in Jboss 7 from MBean? (Naming context is read-only)

Tags: jndi, jmx, jboss7.x, mbeans

When binding object to JNDI from MBean (legacy code to jboss 7.1) i am getting following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JBAS011859: Naming context is read-only
    at org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.requireOwner(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:126)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.createSubcontext(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:116)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.createSubcontext(NamingContext.java:338)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.createSubcontext(InitialContext.java:229)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.createSubcontext(NamingContext.java:346)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.createSubcontext(InitialContext.java:464) [classes.jar:1.6.0_33]
    at org.jboss.as.naming.util.NamingUtils.createSubcontext(NamingUtils.java:63)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.util.NamingUtils.rebind(NamingUtils.java:239)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.util.NamingUtils.rebind(NamingUtils.java:225)
    at com.cdate.hypertable.commons.pool.mgmt.HyperClientConfigMgmt.rebind(HyperClientConfigMgmt.java:79)
```

How can i bind object to JNDI from MBean?
Is it possible to run binding code from MBean in secured context with some "owner"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only write to JNDI during deployment. Some of the options you have are:

- `ServletContextListener`
- `@Startup @Sigleton` EJB
- SAR
- RAR

Comment: I have moved my MBean to a SAR. Stil getting JBAS011859: Naming context is read-only Exception. I am using jboss 7.1.Final.

Comment: I created [AS7-5584](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-5584), let's see where it goes from here.